# smart contract's balance doesn't change in tests

Tags: ink

I'm playing with substrate's ink.
I have written a simple smart contract which deposits funds from a user in a fixed amount.

My problem is with tests (deposit):
When a user sends funds to the contract, I *DO NOT* see that the contract balance changes.

Can someone, please, explain or point me to the documentation
why the contract's balance doesn't change?

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod simple_deposit {

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub enum Error {
    InvalidDepositSize,
}


#[ink(storage)]
pub struct SimpleDeposit {
    pub total_deposited: Balance,
    pub deposit_size: Balance,
}

impl SimpleDeposit {
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new(deposit_size: Balance) -> Self {
        Self { total_deposited: 0,
               deposit_size: deposit_size,
        }
    }

    #[ink(message)]
    pub fn balance(&self) -> Balance {
        self.total_deposited
    }

    #[ink(message, payable)]
    pub fn deposit(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        if self.env().transferred_value() != self.deposit_size {
            return Err(Error::InvalidDepositSize);
        }

        self.total_deposited += self.env().transferred_value();

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use ink_lang as ink;
    use ink_lang::codegen::Env;

    use ink_env::test::set_caller as set_caller;
    use ink_env::test::set_value_transferred as set_value_transferred;

    fn bob_account() -> AccountId {
        ink_env::test::default_accounts::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>().bob
    }

    #[ink::test]
    fn constructor() {
        let simple_deposit = SimpleDeposit::new(15);

        assert_eq!(simple_deposit.total_deposited, 0);
        assert_eq!(simple_deposit.deposit_size, 15);
    }

    #[ink::test]
    fn deposit() {
        let mut simple_deposit = SimpleDeposit::new(15);
        let balance_before = simple_deposit.env().balance();

        set_caller::<Environment>(bob_account());
        set_value_transferred::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(15);
        let res = simple_deposit.deposit();
        assert!(res.is_ok());

        let balance_after = simple_deposit.env().balance();

        assert_ne!(balance_before, balance_after);
    }
}
```

Sorry, I haven't searched the substrate.stackexchange yet (lack of time, maybe, will do it later).

Thanks in advance for any advices and suggestions!

here is the link to the gist on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/vni/fb897f32244e8ff6931b286bb926a191#file-substrate-simple_deposit-ink-rs

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `set_value_transferred` set the value transferred from the caller but [does not update the balances](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/268e80a99b19af93d13fc904b20ee69f3ac1f243/crates/engine/src/test_api.rs#L257)

I could reproduce with this test on the [contract-trasnfer example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/contract-transfer/lib.rs) in ink repo:

```
#[ink::test]
fn test_transferred_value() {
    // given
    let accounts = default_accounts();
    let mut give_me = create_contract(100);

    // when
    // Push the new execution context which sets Eve as caller and
    // the `mock_transferred_value` as the value which the contract
    // will see as transferred to it.
    set_sender(accounts.eve);
    give_me.give_me(20);

    ink_env::test::set_value_transferred::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(10);

    assert_eq!(get_balance(accounts.eve), 20);

    give_me.was_it_ten();

    // Panic - Should be 10
    assert_eq!(get_balance(accounts.eve), 10);
}
```

You can open an issue in ink! repo

Comment: Thank you very much! : )
Later will try your test, look in the sources and fire up an ink issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

The off-chain engine used for contract tests did not provide means for automatically moving funds along while making contract (payable) message invocation. We have fixed that now by introducing the [`pay_with_call!()`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/macro.pay_with_call.html) macro.